# Visual Studio Code PHP Документация

Tags: php, документация, visual-studio-code, phpdoc, intellisense

Есть ли возможность нормально подсвечивать документацию по функциям в Visual Studio Code?
На данный момент, intellisense умеет только подсветить все, что без параметров через `@`, как на картинке ниже.

[image: Подсветка документирования]

Стандартизованные стили форматирования нормально отображать он не хочет, как показано на рисунке ниже:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы узнать, может я не так готовлю intellisense? Или есть какие-нибудь экстеншены для этого?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решилось установкой [Intelephense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client) и пользованием документирования в формате `PHPDoc`:

```
/**
 * @param string $test
 * @return bool
 */
```